# reactjs ToggleButtonGroup with type radio is not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I am trying to implement button group in reactjs es6. now i have taken this example https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/button-group/ with the checkbox and I am trying to implement but it does not seem to trigger the onchange event.

```
    class ToggleButtonGroupControlled extends React.Component {
          constructor(props, context) {
            super(props, context);

            //this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

            this.state = {
              value: 1
            };
          }

          handleChange(e) {
              console.log(e);
            this.setState({ value: e });
          }

          render() {
            return (
              <ToggleButtonGroup
                type="radio"
                    name="exemption_status_button"
                value={this.state.value}
                onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
              defaultChecked={this.state.value}
              >
                <ToggleButton onChange={this.handleChange}value={1} className="badge2" data-count={this.props.statusButton.requested}>Requested</ToggleButton>
                <ToggleButton onChange={this.handleChange}value={3} className="badge2" data-count={this.props.statusButton.accepted}>Accepted</ToggleButton>
                <ToggleButton onChange={this.handleChange}value={6} className="badge2" data-count={this.props.statusButton.implemented}>Implemented</ToggleButton>
                <T

oggleButton onChange={this.handleChange}value={5} className="badge2" data-count={this.props.statusButton.cancelled}>Cancelled</ToggleButton>
            <ToggleButton onChange={this.handleChange}value={4} className="badge2" data-count={this.props.statusButton.rejected}>Rejected</ToggleButton>
          </ToggleButtonGroup>
        );
      }
    }
```

i got it working the following way. I had to use jquery to extract the value and use passback functions .

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Checkbox } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {
    fetchSecurityExemptions,
    fetchSecurityExemptionsCount,
    fetchMarkets,
    fetchServiceDomains,
    fetchServicesList,
    fetchSecurityEngineerList,
    fetchBusinessPriorityList,
    updateSecurityExemption
} from '../../actions/security';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { Button, ButtonToolbar, Modal, Tooltip, OverlayTrigger, ToggleButton, ToggleButtonGroup } from 'react-bootstrap';
import FontAwesome from 'react-fontawesome';
import { BootstrapTable, TableHeaderColumn, InsertModalHeader, InsertModalFooter, SearchField } from 'react-bootstrap-table';
import 'react-bootstrap-table/dist/react-bootstrap-table-all.min.css';
import $ from 'jquery';
import ModalError from '../modalerror';
import ModalConfirm from '../modalconfirm';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { isGenericName } from '../../scripts/validation';

class ToggleButtonGroupControlled extends Component {
      constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

        this.value = 1

      }

      handleChange(e) {
        this.value = $(e.target).children('input').val();
        this.passStatusButtonBack();
      }

      passStatusButtonBack(){
          this.props.passStatusButtonBack(this.value);
      }

      render() {
        return (
        <ButtonToolbar>
          <ToggleButtonGroup
            type="radio"
            name="exemption_status_button"
            value={this.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            defaultChecked={this.value}
          >
            <ToggleButton onClick={this.handleChange}value={1} className="badge2" data-count={this.props.statusButton.requested}>Requested</ToggleButton>
            <ToggleButton onClick={this.handleChange}value={3} className="badge2" data-count={this.props.statusButton.accepted}>Accepted</ToggleButton>
            <ToggleButton onClick={this.handleChange}value={6} className="badge2" data-count={this.props.statusButton.implemented}>Implemented</ToggleButton>
            <ToggleButton onClick={this.handleChange}value={5} className="badge2" data-count={this.props.statusButton.cancelled}>Cancelled</ToggleButton>
            <ToggleButton onClick={this.handleChange}value={4} className="badge2" data-count={this.props.statusButton.rejected}>Rejected</ToggleButton>
          </ToggleButtonGroup>
        </ButtonToolbar>
        );
      }
    }


class SecurityExemptions extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.securityExemptions = [];
        this.state = {
            viewport: {
                width: window.innerWidth,
                height: window.innerHeight
            },
            data: [],
            show: false,
            showError: false,
            errorMsg: '',
            errorTitle: '',
            confirm: {
                body: '',
                show: false,
                id: '',
                next: null
            },
            totalDataSize: 0,
            currentPage: 1,
            statusButton: {value: 1, requested: 0, accepted: 0, implemented: 0, cancelled:0, rejected: 0}
        };
        this.where = [];
        this.sort = 'id desc';
        this.meta = { title: '', description: 'Lists and manages security exemptions' };
        this.options = {
            noDataText: 'Loading...',
            defaultSortName: 'id',
            defaultSortOrder: 'desc',
            page: 1,
            paginationShowsTotal: true,
            sizePerPage: 50,
            sizePerPageList: [10, 25, 50, 100, 250],
            onPageChange: this.onPageChange.bind(this),
            onSizePerPageList: this.onSizePerPageList.bind(this),
            onFilterChange: this.onFilterChange.bind(this),
            onSortChange: this.onSortChange.bind(this),
            selectRowProp: {
                mode: 'checkbox',
                clickToSelect: true,
                onSelect: this.handleRowSelect,
                customComponent: this.customMultiSelect.bind(this)
            },
            cellEditProp: {
                mode: 'click',
                blurToSave: true,           
                afterDeleteRow: this.onAfterDeleteRow.bind(this),
                afterSaveCell: this.onAfterSaveCell.bind(this),
                nonEditableRows: function() {
                    return this.state.data.filter(row => row.exemption_status_id != 1 ).map(row => row.id);
                  }.bind(this)
            },
            handleConfirmDeleteRow: this.customConfirm.bind(this),
            btnGroup: this.createCustomButtonGroup.bind(this),
            deleteBtn: this.createCustomDeleteButton.bind(this),
            onSearchChange: this.onSearchChange.bind(this),
            searchField: this.createCustomSearchField            
        };

        this.updateWindowDimensions = this.updateWindowDimensions.bind(this);
        this.handleShowError = this.handleShowError.bind(this);
        this.fetchSecurityExemptions = this.fetchSecurityExemptions.bind(this);
        this.handlestatusButtonChange = this.handlestatusButtonChange.bind(this);
        this.runOnce = false;
        this.passStatusButtonBack = this.passStatusButtonBack.bind(this)

        this.markets = [];
        this.serviceDomain = [];
        this.servicesList = [];
        this.servicesListDisplay = [];
        this.securityEngineerList = [];
        this.businessPriority = []        
    }

    passStatusButtonBack(status){
        let statusButton = this.state.statusButton;
        statusButton.value = status;
        this.setState({ statusButton });
        this.where.exemption_status_id = status;
        this.fetchSecurityExemptions(this.options.page, this.options.sizePerPage, this.where, this.sort);
    }    


    passMetaBack = () => {
        this.props.passMetaBack(this.meta);
    };



    createCustomButtonGroup = props => {    
            return (
                <ButtonGroup className="my-custom-class" sizeClass="btn-group-md">
                    {props.insertBtn}
                    {props.deleteBtn}
                    <ExemptionStatusButtons self={this} />
                    <ToggleButtonGroupControlled statusButton={this.state.statusButton} passStatusButtonBack={this.passStatusButtonBack}/>
                </ButtonGroup>
            );

    };



    componentDidMount() {
        this.passMetaBack();
        this.updateWindowDimensions();
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.updateWindowDimensions);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', this.updateWindowDimensions);
    }

    renderTable(tableData) {
        let insertRow = false;
        let deleteRow = false;

        return (
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="row-fluid">
                    <BootstrapTable 
                        data={tableData} 
                        remote 
                        search 
                        fetchInfo={{ dataTotalSize: this.state.totalDataSize }} 
                        options={this.options} 
                        pagination 
                        striped 
                        hover 
                        tableHeaderClass="table-vf thead" 
                        tableContainerClass="securityExemptions" 
                        insertRow={insertRow} 
                        cellEdit={this.options.cellEditProp} 
                        deleteRow={deleteRow} 
                        selectRow={this.options.selectRowProp} 
                        maxHeight={this.state.viewport.height * 0.66} 
                        ref="table"
                    >
                        <TableHeaderColumn dataField="id" isKey={true} editable={false} hiddenOnInsert width={`60px`} dataFormat={this.exemptionsLink}>
                            ID
                        </TableHeaderColumn>
                        <TableHeaderColumn dataField="hits" editable={false} hiddenOnInsert width={`50px`}>
                            Hits
                        </TableHeaderColumn>
                        <TableHeaderColumn dataField="market" width={`150px`} formatExtraData={this.markets} editable={{ type: 'select', options: { values: this.markets } }}>
                            Market
                        </TableHeaderColumn>
                        <TableHeaderColumn dataField="service_domain" width={`150px`} formatExtraData={this.serviceDomain} editable={{ type: 'select', options: { values: this.serviceDomain } }}>
                            Service Domain
                        </TableHeaderColumn>
                        <TableHeaderColumn dataField="service_id" width={`200px`}  editable={false} dataFormat={this.serviceFormatter}>
                            Service / Project / Programme
                        </TableHeaderColumn>
                        <TableHeaderColumn dataField="demand_ref"  width={`70px`} editable={{ type: 'text', validator: this.isGenericName }}>
                            Demand ID
                        </TableHeaderColumn>
                        <TableHeaderColumn dataField="summary"  width={`200px`} editable={false}>
                            Summary
                        </TableHeaderColumn>
                        <TableHeaderColumn dataField="filename" width={`200px`} dataFormat={this.commsMatrixLink} editable={false}>
                            Commsmatrix
                        </TableHeaderColumn>
                        <TableHeaderColumn dataField="business_priority" width={`100px`} formatExtraData={this.businessPriority} editable={{ type: 'select', options: { values: this.businessPriority } }}>
                            Priority
                        </TableHeaderColumn>
                        <TableHeaderColumn dataField="expiry_date" width={`150px`} editable={true}>
                            Expiry
                        </TableHeaderColumn>
                        <TableHeaderColumn dataField="security_engineer" width={`200px`} dataFormat={this.htmlFormatter} formatExtraData={this.securityEngineerList} editable={{ type: 'select', options: { values: this.securityEngineerList } }}>
                            Security Engineer
                        </TableHeaderColumn>
                        <TableHeaderColumn dataField="ts_created" width={`130px`} editable={false} hiddenOnInsert>
                            Requested
                        </TableHeaderColumn>
                        <TableHeaderColumn dataField="created_by" width={`110px`} editable={false} hiddenOnInsert>
                            Requested By
                        </TableHeaderColumn>
                    </BootstrapTable>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

    render() {
        const { securityExemptions } = this.props;

        if (!this.runOnce && this.props.isReady && this.securityExemptions.length == 0) {
            this.runOnce = true;

            this.where = {exemption_status_id : this.state.statusButton.value};
            this.initData();
        }

        let table = (
            <div>
                Loading...<i className="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" />
            </div>
        );

        if (this.state.show) {
            table = this.renderTable(this.state.data);
            this.moveElement();
        }

        return (
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="row-fluid top-buffer">{table}</div>
                <ModalConfirm body={this.state.confirm.body} show={this.state.confirm.show} id={this.state.confirm.id} handleConfirmYes={this.handleConfirmYes} handleConfirmNo={this.handleConfirmNo} />
                <ModalError title={this.state.errorTitle} body={this.state.errorMsg} show={this.state.showError} handleCloseError={this.handleCloseError} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        securityExemptions: state.securityExemptions,
        listsReducer: state.listsReducer
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators(
        {
            fetchSecurityExemptions,
            fetchSecurityExemptionsCount,
            fetchMarkets,
            fetchServiceDomains,
            fetchServicesList,
            fetchSecurityEngineerList,
            fetchBusinessPriorityList,
            updateSecurityExemption
        },
    dispatch
);
```

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SecurityExemptions);

}

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation the onChange should be given on the `ToggleButtonGroup` component and not on `ToggleButton` component,

```
<ToggleButtonGroup
        type="checkbox"
        value={this.state.value}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      >
        <ToggleButton value={1}>Checkbox 1 (pre-checked)</ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton value={2}>Checkbox 2</ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton value={3}>Checkbox 3 (pre-checked)</ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton value={4} disabled>
          Checkbox 4 (disabled)
        </ToggleButton>
</ToggleButtonGroup>
```

Edit: If that doesnt work, you can always use,

```
handleClick = (e)=>{
   console.log(e.target.value)
}

<ToggleButton onClick={this.handleClick}value={1} className="badge2" data-count={this.props.statusButton.requested}>Requested</ToggleButton>
```

Comment: i have `onChange ` on the `ToggleButtonGroup` but it does not work if the `type` is radio.

Comment: Did you try after removing onchange from ToggleButton ??

Comment: I have added one more method

Comment: @shorif2000 Did you try with the second method? by using onclick?